# Load specific external content in bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to load external content from a specific div into a Bootstrap 3.3.x Modal?

Here's my setup:

Page 1 = `mywebsite.com/doctors`, which will open the modal.

Page 2 = `mywebsite.com/doctors/john-doe`, which has a div named `#bio`.

Can I load the content from `#bio` into the modal on Page 1?

I've found info on loading a full external page into the modal, but I really need to load only the content from a specific div.

I pieced together this bit of ajax for loading a specific element, but I'm not sure how to integrate it with the bootstrap modal (or if it's even the best way to do this).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mywebsite.com/doctors/john-doe',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        var div = $('#bio', $(html)).addClass('done');
        $('.modal-content').html(div);
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load)

> Loading Page Fragments
>
> The `.load()` method, unlike `$.get()`, allows us to specify a portion
>   of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the `url` parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.
>
> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document
>   that is fetched:
>
> `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );`

```
$(".modal-content").load("mywebsite.com/doctors/john-doe #bio"
, function(html, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  // do stuff when `#bio` element at `mywebsite.com/doctors/john-doe`
  // loaded as `html` of `.modal-content`
});
```

Comment: Here's my complete working code in the modal callback in case anyone needs it. I also decided to pull in the URL via a data attribute "data-load-url" for more flexibility:  `$('#doc-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { var button = $(e.relatedTarget);  var loadurl = button.data('load-url'); $(this).find('.modal-content').load(loadurl + ' #bio'); });`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in the right path.

You'll have to inject this ajax `html` content received from `mywebsite.com/doctors/john-doe`into the dialog's `modal-body`.

[Bootstrap modal dialog](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) html structure:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

So, one approach is something like that: (1) open dialog with an loading spinner, (2) trigger this ajax request (3) in the success callback call `$('.modal-body').html` to set this div content with the received response.

### Partial content

One option of parsing received html content is to put your html inside jQuery constructor, like `var content = $(received_html);`. Then you cand find your desired div with `content.find('#myDiv');`.